# Map with two key values

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have an assignment where I need to go through all the files in a folder. For each file I need to know each unique file extension, how many files for each unique file extension, and the total size for each unique file extension. I have to be able to sort through this using either the file extension or the total size of the file extension. The first thing I thought of using was a map. This will keep track of each unique file extension and the amount of times that file extension was found. How do I now associate the total size of the file extension to my map? So for example I need the output to be something like this:

Using file extension for sort
.cpp : 1 : 3400
.exe : 3 : 3455600
.mp4 : 25 : 200000404

Using total file extension size for sort
.mp4 : 25 : 200000404
.exe : 3 : 3455600
.cpp : 1 : 3400

Here is the code I have after some editing:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <filesystem>
    #include <map>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::tr2::sys;

    class fileInfo {
    public:
        int fileCount;
        long long fileSize;
    };

    void scan(path f)
    {
        map<string, fileInfo> fileMap;
        cout << "Scanning = " << system_complete(f) << endl;
        directory_iterator d(f);
        directory_iterator e;
        for( ; d != e; ++d)
        {
            path p = d->path();
            cout << "\nExtension is: " << extension(p) << "\tFile size is: " << file_size(p) << endl;
            fileMap[extension(p)].fileCount ++;
            fileMap[extension(p)].fileSize += file_size(p);
        }

        for (map<string, fileInfo>::iterator it = fileMap.begin(); it != fileMap.end(); ++it)
        {
             cout << it->first << " : " << it->second.fileCount << " : " << it->second.fileSize << endl;
        }
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
    {
        path folder = "..";

        scan(folder);

        return 0;
     }
```

EDIT: So I have implemented the class fileInfo. It is sort of working. But I am having a problem with the file_size. After the first run through the loop, it correctly returns the file_size, but for every other run through the loop file_size is returning 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one map:

```
 map<string, vector<int> > fileExtToSizeMap;
```

Basically, for each file extension in `string` format, if the current file is associated with that extension, put the size of the file into the vector `vector<int>`. After you finished scanning the directory, the size of that vector will tell you `how many files are associated with the file extension` and the sum of the vector will tell you `the total size for each unique file extension`. You two major questions are then answered by this data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a data structure eg `ExtensionStat` like this:

```
struct ExtensionStat {
  int totalFile;
  int totalSize;
};
```

And have a map from extension name into the stat

```
map<string, ExtensionStat> extMap;
```

Then you just iterate contents of your folder collecting the statistics into `extMap`. Keep in mind you don't need to use struct, you can use class too. Also you can choose the map to be `map<string, ExtensionStat*> extMap;` if you'd like to avoid full value copying

Comment: How would I populate the map though?

Comment: Use operator[] or insert method

Comment: This is what I have tried, don't know if I am going about this in the right way ...

class extStat {
public:
 int fileCount_;
 int fileSize_;
};

void scan(path f)
{
 extStat ext;
 map<string, extStat> map;
 cout << "Scanning = " << system_complete(f) << endl;
 directory_iterator d(f);
 directory_iterator e;
 for( ; d != e; ++d)
 {
  path p = d->path();
  int temp = file_size(p);
  ext.fileCount_++;
  ext.fileSize_ += temp;
  map[extension(p)]ext;
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a multi-map

```
map<string, size_t> fileExtSizeMap;
```

Simple add a new entry for every file encountered.

std::lower_bound and std::upperbound can be used to search this structure. Use std::distance on resulting iterators to get a file count.

Or simply iterate through the complete map incrementing a counter as you go.